# how to find the amount of space in a directory or the partition directory is in

Tags: file, bash, unix, filesystems, directory

I want to write a script that fills a directory with music until there's a certain amount of space left. The directory may be on various partitions and I don't know how to ask a directory for free space or it's partition.

```
pseudocode
fill(directory)
  until < 100 mb of free space in directory
    copy music to directory
```

How would you do it using unix tools like bash, find, etc.

Comment: Any particular full path, i.e. a directory, like /path/2/music/classic/bruckner can only live on 1 partition. Any files put in that specific directory will all be in the same partition. However, if there are subdirs below that, they may be mounted to other disks, BUT they won't affect what any specific directory can hold, right? So this simplifies your problem some to 'What is the available disk space for the current directory?' (Unless you have multiple processes writing files to the same partition area). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean you have a specific directory, on a specific partition that you wish to fill until there is only 100 MB left.

The df command will return the amount of disk space left on a given directory's disk/partition.

```
df musicfolder/
```

The fourth column will give free space

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            151733412  24153792 119871924  17% /
```

you can use awk to gain the fourth column value and ignore the headers. So your script will be something like:

```
freespace=$(df /musicfolder | awk 'FNR>1{print $4}')

while [ $freespace -gt 10000000 ] ; do
    (copy files from wherever)
    freespace=$(df ~/musicfolder | awk 'FNR>1{print $4}')
done
```

Comment: Omg. I looked at "du", "fdisk", "stat", etc. But didn't look to see whether or not "df" takes an argument. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Linux's `df` will tell you exactly that. To find the free space on the volume a folder resides in, execute:

```
df -h /home/chris/directory
```

Output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
server:/vol/home      2.0T  1.3T  759G  63% /home/chris
```

Omit the `-h` flag to get raw bytes instead of the human-readable K/M/G/T.

**EDIT** Just because I'm bored, I went ahead and wrote a script for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
fillDir='/mnt/fillMe'
musicFile='/home/chris/Yakety Sax.mp3'

while [ `df -P "$fillDir" | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'` -gt 100000000 ]
do
  echo `df -Ph "$fillDir" | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'` space left.
  cp "$musicFile" "$fillDir"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is great too. I'm probably only gonna use the df part of this and switch to ruby for the rest, but this is great. Thank you.